# array.forEach de JavaScript no funciona en Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, foreach, navegador-web

Buen día. Revisando mi aplicación en otros navegadores recordé (por las malas) que **IE** no me aceptaba las `arrow functions` de `JavaScript`. Así que reemplace todas por funciones normales. 
Ahora, el problema lo tengo en una función `forEach` que recorre un `array`.

```
respuesta.forEach(menu => {
    if (menu["dmc"] == "si") {
        selectDmc.append('<option value="' + menu["id"] + '">' + menu["nombre"] + '</option>');
    }  else {
        selectComedor.append('<option value="' + menu["id"] + '">' + menu["nombre"] + '</option>');
    }
}
```

En este bloque me tira el error nuevamente en la flechita `=>`, pero leyendo la documentación de `array.forEach()`, entiendo que no es lo mismo reemplazar `(menu)=>` por `function(menu)`, y probándolo tampoco resulta.

Hay alguna manera a través de la cual yo pueda implementar la función de arriba y ésta sea compatible con la mayoría de los navegadores?

Comment: si te vas a la pagina de [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com) al apartado de [forEach](https://caniuse.com/#search=forEach) y ves en compatibilidad IE no soporta esta opcion. deberas usar el for clasico o `jquery` que aun brinda el soporte para navegadores viejos!

Comment: Exactamente esa se hace como comentas en tu pregunta, con una función anonima `.forEach(function(menu){});` en **IE 9+**. En la pregunta no has especificado la versión. Como comenta Bryro comprueba la compatibilidad entre `forEach` y tu versión de IE

Comment: Es la version 11.0, y tenés toda la razón. Efectivamente soluciona el problema, cosa que no me daba cuenta porque estaba devolviendo otro error en otra linea: ``setTimeout(() => {}`` donde tengo otra flecha. Ahora no se como solucionar esta parte jaja! Deberia borrar esta pregunta y realizar una nueva? Perdon las molestias

Comment: Que bobo, con añadir cualquier parámetro ya estaba. ``setTimeout(function(e)){}`` solucionó el último de mis problemas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El método [`Array.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/forEach#Compatibilidad_con_navegadores) está soportado por Internet Explorer desde la versión 9 (que ya no recibe soporte de Microsoft y no se debería usar).

El método[`NodeList.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach#Compatibilidad_en_Navegadores) NO está soportado por Internet Explorer. Esta clase [es usada para obtener listas de elementos](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/NodeList) (por ejemplo al usar `document.querySelectorAll`) y muchas veces sus instancias son confundidas con instancias de Array.

Si estás trabajando con Internet Explorer puedes añadir estos métodos a esas clases usando una librería polyfill/shim o implementando el método tú mismo.

Las *funciones flecha* tendrás que reescribirlas o usar algún transpilador como [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) para transformarlas automáticamente (hay que tener cuidado con el contexto, el `this`, si lo haces manualmente).